# MS Access Retrieving/Setting .Value from ListBox with Query as RowSource

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox

I have been utterly stymied in my attempts to retrieve and/or assign a value to a listbox with a Select query as the Row Source. Here is the set up:

I have a form for submitting Returns for products, `frmIssueRMA`, which is related to `tblRMA`. There is a section where the user can type/select the `SerialNumber` from a `combobox`, which is data housed in a different table, tblUnits. Once a selection is made, it sets off a daisy-chain of `AfterUpdate` events which requery listboxes that display Unit details from various other tables. Largely this is simply informative, and the fields are locked for display purposes only. However, there is one such field that I do need to retrieve the value of for later use that I cannot seem to accomplish.

The field is `txtAssembly`, and it has a row source of:

```
 SELECT tblUnits.PartNumber 
 FROM tblUnits 
 WHERE (((tblUnits.SerialNumber)=[TempVars]![SerialNumber]));
```

(the `SerialNumber` temporary variable is apart of the `AfterUpdate` events for the `cboSerialNumber` if it matters)

It properly shows the correct part number, but I cannot seem to get at it to use it. For example, I have tried an `AfterUpdate` event on the field itself using `TempVars.Add "Assembly", Me.txtAssembly.Value`. This does not seem to work as the field isn't actually entered, so I added that line to the VBA for the `cboSerialNumber` `AfterUpdate` event after `Me.txtAssembly.Requery`. This also does not work. The implication, it seems to me then, is that it is not creating (or does not actually have) a value, even after it queries successfully.

I have attempted to use `DLookUp`, and this too does not seem to work. I even attempted to pull the value into a different textbox by using `=[txtAssembly].[Value] and =[txtAssembly].[Text]`. Silly I know, but it was a hail mary.

I would truly appreciate any tips or suggestions you may have on how I can capture/retrieve/reference the part number that is displayed after the requery in the list box. I hope I provided enough detail, but if I can clarify or expand upon anything please let me know.

Comment: If you go to your immediate windows (`Ctrl + G`) and type in `MsgBox Forms!frmIssueRMA.txtAssembly.Value` what do you get?

Comment: If I just put in Forms!frmIssueRMA.txtAssembly.Value it returns Null, even though the box does display a part number.

Comment: How/where is '[TempVars]![SerialNumber]' created - a Class module? To confirm, I believe you are saying that after you select a serial number from the combobox, events run to populate your listbox, which is named 'txtAssembly'? And you can SEE the value in the listbox but you can't access it?

Comment: Wayne, that is correct. When a selection is made in the serial number combo box, an AfterUpdate VBA code triggers which .requeries several listboxes and adds the temporary variable SerialNumber based on the selection

Comment: Is there a reason why you use the Class module to access SerialNumber instead of just getting the selected entry from the ListBox? If you post your code, I can offer some suggestions to debug/solve the issue.